# Why is there a *minimum* energy for a particle to be captured in a $r^{-3}$ potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, orbital-motion, scattering-cross-section

I was stuck in a central force problem from David Morin's Book "Introduction to Classical Mechanics".

> The problem states that suppose there is a particle of mass $m$ moving under the central potential $V(r)=-\frac{C}{3r^3}$ from infinity with initial velocity $u$ and impact parameter $b$. Then what is the largest value of $b$ for which the particle will get captured by the potential?

While solving the problem I was thinking what might be the condition for capture? Apparently, it seems logical to say that if the particle has an energy $(E)$ which is less than the maximum value of effective potential $V_{max}$ then the motion will be bounded and the particle will get captured.

But while looking for the solution I find that the condition is totally opposite i.e. the condition for capture is $E \ge V_{max}$. It seems quite counterintuitive because I would think that smaller energies would lead to capture because the particle wouldn't have enough energy to escape the potential, whereas large energy particles could escape.

Can anyone provide me any insight about what is the logic behind this condition they have applied?

I am attatching an screenshot of the manual.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the coefficient of the centrifugal barrier $L^2/(2mr^2)$ is held fixed in this analysis, you are varying the energy while keeping angular momentum fixed. With fixed angular momentum, high energy corresponds to low impact parameter, while low energy corresponds to high impact parameter. So it's the high-energy orbits that come close enough to the center of the potential to be captured.

Note that all particles coming from infinity have enough energy, in principle, to escape any potential. But if the potential is $V\propto r^{-2}$ or steeper (yours is $r^{-3}$), energy alone does not determine whether a particle escapes.